# How come my program isn't running and I'm getting Syntax errors? (DrRacket/Scheme)

Tags: list, scheme, element, racket

I'm trying to write a function that would add a new number to the end of a list of numbers but I can't seem to track down and correct my syntax errors. Could someone help me? Thanks!

```
(define (add the-list element)
 (cond 
  ((empty? the-list) (list element)         
   (else (cons (first the-list) cons (add (rest the-list) element))))))

(check-expect (four (list 2 5 4) 1) (list 2 5 4 1)) ; four adds num at the end of lon
```

Comment: Call `check-expect` using `add`, not `four`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of misplaced parentheses, and that second `cons` at the end is wrong, `cons` expects *two* parameters. Try this:

```
(define (add the-list element) 
  (cond ((empty? the-list) (list element))
        (else (cons (first the-list) 
                    (add (rest the-list) element)))))
```

Use Racket's excellent editor to correctly format and indent the code, this kind of problems can be easily detected. Hint: use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to reindent the code, it'll be very useful for spotting syntax errors. As a side note, the same procedure can be implemented more idiomatically by using existing procedures, like this:

```
(define (add the-list element) 
  (append the-list (list element)))
```

Or like this, using a higher-order procedure:

```
(define (add the-list element)
  (foldr cons (list element) the-list))
```